# Pizza Dough Seasoning

Tags: bread, dough, pizza

King Arthur sells pizza dough flavoring on their website. I'm looking to try to homemake some since my dough is a little bland. The ingredients listed include cheese (maybe Parmesan or Romano,) garlic and spices. Any suggestions on what spices would make a good blend?

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Dried oregano, basil, marjoram (probably no more than two out of three of those), onion powder and red pepper flakes would all go just fine.

Answer (score 2):

While you can certainly use any hard grateable cheeses like parmesan, or herbs and spices, traditionally a good pizza dough would be seasoned with nothing but salt.  New York style would also have olive oil.

You should be able to get a very good result with just salt, and maybe the oil.

The toppings sauce and toppings on the pizza normally would be flavored strongly enough to compliment that dough.

Answer (score 0):

What I recommend doing is bake just the dough, no toppings and try and make it as good as possible. It's yummy on it's own and it will give you a great idea where you stand dough wise. Experiment a bit, but really, in my opinion, olive oil, sea salt and a bit of oregano is the farthest I go. If I use tomato sauce and other toppings then I don't go crazy on flavoring the dough.

Answer (score 0):

Agreeing with SAJ14SAJ, can you share your recipe and baking technique? Maybe a lot of room for improvement of the plain crust before you add extra ingredients. My own dough is based on this: http://www.splendidtable.org/recipes/classic-pizza-margherita

Here's my version of her recipe:
    1/2 teaspoon dry yeast
    1/2 cup warm (about 100 degrees) water
    1.25 cups bread flour
    1/2 teaspoon salt

I use double the yeast, and the resulting crust is good enough to eat by itself.

Answer (score 0):

8 tbsp cheddar cheese powder, white or orange
1 tbsp of onion powder
1 tbsp of garlic powder
1 heaping tbsp of Italian seasoning

Experiment by add 1 tbsp to your pizza dough flour mixture